# Related to linear equation with one unknown

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

My question is:
Given that the equation $\,\frac{8}{3}x - a = \frac{9}{4}x + 123\,$ has positive integral solution where a is also positive integer, find the minimum possible value of a.

Please any guidance to  solve this question would be helpful as even after trying a lot I was unable to solve it.

Comment: Do you mean 
$$\frac{8}{3}\,x$$
or 
$$\frac{8}{3x}$$
(and similarly with "9/4x")?

Comment: @user1296721 Please check I edited your question correctly

Comment: @– Zev Chonoles I meant the first one.

Comment: @DonAntonio:Thanks the edit you made is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume you meant $$\frac{8}{3}x-a=\frac{9}{4}x+123\Longleftrightarrow\frac{5}{12}x=123+a\Longleftrightarrow x=\frac{12\cdot 123+12a}{5}$$
As $\,12\cdot 123\,$ ends with a $\,6\,$, we need $\,12a\,$ to end with a $\,4\,$ (to have a multiple of $\,5\,$), and that happens for $\,a=2\,$

Comment: I would like to raise a minor point. Would prefer getting to $5x=12(123+a)$, then observe that the left side is divisible by $5$, so we need the right side to be. So $5$ must divide $123+a$. Smallest positive $a$ that works is $2$.

Comment: @Andre That indeed looks both more elegant and clear.